# How to make the bounced light brighter in unity?

Tags: unity

I'm using indirect lighting to lit a room. The light is coming through the window, but still the inside is too dark compared to the real light . if i bring up the environment or light intensity, it will look the exterior is burnt out ( too bright)... it's already on the limit. How to just make the bounced light (indirect light) brighter ?

Comment: Have you tried adjusting your camera's exposure settings or brightness adaptation?

Comment: i can't find the exposure setting in the camera's  inspector. Where is it ?

Comment: [One flexible option is in the post processing stack](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.postprocessing@2.1/manual/Auto-Exposure.html). Its [tonemapping and colour grading features](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.postprocessing@2.1/manual/Color-Grading.html) may also be useful for you